# How to extract data from the list and put it in the form using jquery

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery

I want to extract data from the list and put it in the form using jquery!

I succeeded to know how to import data from "Last Name" and "First Name" of the list into text fields "Last name" and "First name" of the form by

```
<input type="text" id="lastname"/>

var x="";
x = x + x.get_item('Last_x0020_Name');
$("#lastname").val(x.toString());
```

I still have problem on select field (Age) and textarea filed (description)

[image]

Comment: Do you know the id for the Age field? Is the select field (Age) pre-populated or just or just get the options from the list?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML

```
<label for="ageList">Age from List</label>
<input type="text" id="ageList" />
<br></br>
<label for="ageForm">Age from Form</label>
<input type="text" id="ageForm" />
<br></br>
<label for="myselect">Age Dropdown</label>
<select id="myselect">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
$('#ageList').on('keyup', function () {
var theText = $("#ageList").val().toString();
$('#myselect option[value]').each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr("value") === theText) {
        $(this).attr("selected", "selected");

    }
$('#ageForm').val(theText);
});

});
```

The HTML code is just for reference, I'm sure yours is totally different. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks.

My question now is how to remove a subsrting from a string.
For exemple, when i extract data from a textarea , it appears to me the text that i want and also the balise like this 

div my text div

so i want to delete div and div

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, to remove a substring from a string, one option would be to use replace(). [check this link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)